# Can we replace find_packages with find_namespace_packages in python 3.3 onwards and get rid of the empty init.py files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have a distribution with multiple package and sub packages. There are many empty `__init__.py` files used to tell `setuptools` that the folders are packages.

In python 3.3 onwards, setuptools supports `find_namespace_packages`. So is it a good idea to get rid of the empty `__init__.py` files and replace the find_packages with find_namespace_packages?

Comment: No, it's not a good idea. There are many modules out there with no or wrong behavior implemented for namespace packages (even in the standard library!). Aside from that, I don't see any gains from deleting the `__init__.py` files besides maybe slightly less clutter on disk. If you have lots of packages in your distribution, it may be better to split it into several projects, or flatten the package structure (less packages, more modules). Good question though!

Comment: The gain is that - with a namespace package, I can have multiple distributions that use the same package path. For example Distribution1 can have companyname.department.subdept1.pkgname1, Distribution2 can have companyname.department.subdept2.pkgname2, Distribution3 can have companyname.subdepartment.pkgname3. How else can we achieve such a pattern (companyname.department...) in separate distributions?

Answer (score 4):

There are three ways to [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages), each with its own pros and cons. It is true that `find_namespace_packages` is the recommended solution for Python3+ projects; though remember that this does not mean you omit all `__init__.py` files, you only remove the `__init__.py` in the namespace root.